# Excel using INDEX and LIST to return multiple results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use Excel with the INDEX and LIST functions (rather than VLOOKUP) as I am trying to return multiple results from one worksheet into another.

I've got close with the following formula: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A2:AJ100,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!O2:O100,0),1)` but it is only returning 1 result, how would I return the list of results within the `Sheet1!A2:A100` range which match the content of `B1` against the data in `Sheet1!O2:O100` range?

The range of data I want to retrieve will be unique, the matching criteria won't be.

Multiple website about matching multiple criteria and returning 1 result, but very few about multiple matches to 1 criteria and returning all the results. Thanks

Comment: Sorry guys, I was under the impression I couldn't use `VLOOKUP` as it would only return 1 result! Seems my google search was wrong and it can! Thanks & apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: Well, you were right; you can't use VLOOKUP to return multiple values. The title of the duplicate post is a little misleading since none of the answers utilize VLOOKUP.